# Easiest way to playback jpg on a stand-alone LCD monitor

Tags: hardware-rec, lcd, media, slideshow

I have an LCD on a stand and I want to playback some pictures. One way would be to get an LCD with a media card reader and just put those pictures on there.

Are there any other solutions out there? Maybe a wireless media player that connects to a computer and does the playback of jpg's from there? Any links?

Any LCD's out there that have network cards embedded and some software that I can use to stream photos from anther computer onto that LCD?

Any other suggestions? I am looking for something ergonomic.

**EDIT** I would really like a *wireless* solution if possible

**EDIT 2** I'm not talking about a regular digital picture frame solution here. The pictures are high quality and the display should be at least 19".

Comment: so... basically you're looking for a wireless, ergonomic digital pictureframe.

Comment: btw, i don't think you mean "ergonomic".  i've no idea what you might mean, but "ergonomic" generally refers to chairs and keyboards and mice, and whether they're good for someone to use a lot.

Comment: What I mean by "ergonomic" is "no cables and least amount of hardware".

Comment: that's reeeally not what that word means.

Comment: Seems like Ergonomics is the science of designing the job, equipment, and workplace to fit the worker. In this case, "no cables" fits the worker better than "with cables"

Comment: i don't disagree with that notion, but i and most other english speakers won't read the word "ergonomic" and think "oh, no cables".  if you mean "no cables", say "no cables", don't say "ergonomic".

Comment: You're right, in general you cannot disagree with the definition of a word :) Also, if it is not clear enough for you what it means to have an "ergonomic" setup of any hardware than ask what it means in this context instead of lecturing on the meaning of the word. And yeah, it is possible even for...ahem, "non-English" speakers to read a word and actually think exactly what it means.

Comment: You're stretching quite a bit, tzup. By your definition my old Razr is ergonomic. No cables and not much hardware. My quad core CPU is ergonomic because it suits me well to not have to wait for my computer to do stuff. My car is ergonomic because it suits me better than the bus. Those statements may be true, but they aren't useful. Perhaps you meant "aesthetically pleasing?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this before, it is hard work, but this [site](http://www.shuttertalk.com/articles/digitalframe#introduction) helped me through the process

> For my project, I wanted a desktop quality LCD screen of a size equivalent to an 11”x14” photograph. I also wanted professional quality matting and framing. My wife was skeptical about the project, and I knew that if the frame did not look great, it would be banished to the family room, instead of being mounted in a place of honor in the living room.

For a wireless option i suggest this [Popular Science article](http://www.popsci.com/diy/article/2006-04/diy-digital-photo-frame)

> 1. IBM ThinkPad T21, 800-megahertz Pentium III processor, 10-gigabyte hard drive, 14.1-inch LCD: free (donated)
> 2. Custom 151/4-by-123/4-inch polished zinc frame with mat and mounting boards: $50; americanframe.com
> 3. Cnet Wi-Fi card: $30; newegg.com

Comment: Thanks for the resource, very nice project indeed. However, I need more of a digital signage wireless solution that is affordable and suitable for such a small task.

Comment: Please look at the edit i have done